# Accessing session from Spring Web Flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow, spring-portlet-mvc

I am using **Spring Web Flow** inside **Spring Portlet** (that's important within a portlet)

**How can I get session (HttpSession) object from web flow ???**

I know that spring provides special variables like `externalContext` or `flowRequestContext`,
but I can't figure out how to get session from that objects

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Portlet Webflow combination: 
You can access sessionMap through externalContext. For porlets the implementation of this is by [PortletExternalContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.x/api/org/springframework/webflow/context/portlet/PortletExternalContext.html) which has two session maps available: globalSessionMap and sessionMap.
You can access it as:

```
    <evaluate expression="externalContext.globalSessionMap.yourSessionAttribute" result="store it somewhere"/>

    <evaluate expression="externalContext.sessionMap.yourSessionAttribute" result="store it somewhere"/>
```

In ServletContext, these maps return the same value.

**UPDATE:**

If you need explicit access to session(portlet session) itself instead of attributes through sessionMap as mentioned above, you can get it as:

```
   <evaluate expression="externalContext.nativeRequest.portletSession" result="store this session object somewhere"/>
```

Here nativeRequest object is [PortletRequest](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.portlet/portlet-api/2.0/javax/portlet/PortletRequest.java#PortletRequest.getPortletSession%28boolean%29) object.

Having said all these, if the attributes are placed in APPLICATION_SCOPE in portlet session then they can be accessed in servlet session scope. 
I doubt if you can get HttpSession object as such but the attributes can be.